# Why does dereferencing two handles to the same pointer result in this unexpected behavior?

Tags: c++, c, pointers, dereference

```
typedef struct node_t {
    char val;
    node_t * next;
};


void removeNodeByVal(node_t * head, char to_remove) {
    //get head pointer pointer
    node_t** pp = &head;
    node_t** fpp = &head;
    
    // get head pointer
    node_t* entry = head;

    while (entry) {
        if (entry->val == to_remove) {
            *pp = entry->next;
            //*fpp = entry->next <--- this isn't working for me;

            return;
        }
            

        pp = &entry->next;
        entry = entry->next;
        fpp = &entry;
    }
}
```

In the above code snippet, the code only removes the target node if `pp` is used as a pointer-pointer to grab the address of an entry in the link list and change it to point to the next node. If I use `fpp` as a handle, then the node's address isn't changed, even though `fpp` and `pp` point to the same address. Anyone know why?

Comment: My guess is that there might be undefined behavior because at the end of the linked list the entry would be NULL (or NULLPTR), and getting address of NULL would cause problems. It is still annoying me though.

Comment: Whether `*pp = entry->next;` or `*fpp = entry->next;`, either way you're only modifying `head`, from your parameter list... which is local to the function.  If you're trying to modify the variable you passed in, in its own scope, you need to pass `node_t **` instead of `node_t *` instead of trying to add the extra indirection inside the function body (which doesn't work).  You need to pass the address of the pointer you want to modify... right now you pass its value, then get a pointer to the parameter you copied it to and modify your parameter through it (instead of the original pointer var)

Comment: ```*pp = entry->next;``` does work though

Comment: It shouldn't.. there's probably something else causing undefined behavior elsewhere, maybe in the function that calls this one.

Comment: I think I see what you're saying. I was messing around with the code, and neither code snippets work to remove the head from the list through indirection. ```*pp = entry->next``` does work only in cases where it's able to get the address of the real pointer through the ```&entry->next``` assignment. I need to study more about using pointers in functions.

Answer (score 0):

If the value of `entry` changes, the value of `&entry->next` will change. Different entries will have their `next` members at different addresses.

However, since `entry` is a local to the `removeNodeByVal` function, `&entry` will always have the same value. Even if the *value* of `entry` changes, it's still the same local variable at the same memory address.

So `&entry` and `&entry->next` will have totally different behavior. One will not change with the value of `entry` and be a constant throughout the function and the other will change value with every iteration of the loop.